# Not able to prove a not well-defined mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

It is given that the mapping $\alpha= s^{\beta}$ is not well defined for negative reals. Here $s$ is any complex number.

Please can someone explain why is the aforementioned mapping not well defined? The information about not well defined mappings is sparingly spread throughout the internet but I am not able to understand, how to go ahead and solve this problem.

I have solved until the solution of $s$ as given below:

$s = |\alpha|^{1/\beta} \angle (\frac{arg(\alpha) + 2l\pi}{\beta})$

But I am not able to understand, how to prove that the mapping $\alpha= s^{\beta}$ is not well-defined. Please explain

Comment: Will you please explain a bit detail about your map $\alpha=s^\beta$ because I think the possible answer that why it is not defined for the negative real axis is because, $Log (\alpha)=\beta Log (s)$, $Log$ is not defined for the negative real axis.

Comment: `\beta` is any rational number like 0.5, 1.2, 1.3, etc. `s` is any complex number. `\alpha` is  the function value. Please can you explain in what range is this mapping valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) but for now, the domain of definition of $Log$ function is $\mathbb{C}-\{z\in\mathbb{C}:Re(z)\le 0\text{ and }Im(z)= 0\}$. Here is the geometrical view. The Sky-Blue region is the domain.

[image]